# Docker Compose: deploying different services from docker-compose.yml to different set of hosts

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

Let's say I have a `docker-compose.yml` file with 3 different services (s1, s2, s3).
Then if I deploy them, on say AWS ECS (just for example) cluster with one host, all the three `containers` will go to that host. If I scale the cluster 2 hosts, then the second hosts, then the second host will also get all the three `containers`.

Ideally, I'd want to have *different* `clusters` for different `services`, so that they can be scaled independently. I'd **not** want to have my *database* container on the same cluster as my `backend` container as both of them have different scaling needs.

How will I achieve this kind of behaviour with docker compose?

Kubernetes has concept of `pods` which kind of provides this abstraction, however since that's not a part of docker, I want to know *how would one develop multi-service application in docker in which each `service` (as defined in docker-compose.yml) can be scaled independently. *

Answer (score 0):

For ECS you would need to either create multiple clusters (i.e. a cluster for each piece of the infrastructure if you're sticking with deploying via compose), or just create multiple tasks. Each task should be a layer in your stack (i.e. api or web, etc). Then you can scale the layers independently.

The big difference you'll find between ECS and K8S is that since ECS uses host port mappings, you can't have 2 different tasks expose the same port and run on the same host.

Check out this aws article as well: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/application_architecture.html

Comment: "a cluster for each piece of the infrastructure if you're sticking with deploying via compose" - But if I am using `ecs-cli` which understands docker-compose.yml, then it just creates one cluster for one compose.yml file.

Comment: Right, if you are deploying via docker-compose then this is your limitation. I'd recommend you create separate tasks and not deploy via compose to solve the problem.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the right way. Also, an ECS `task` can have multiple containers, which is something docker-compose does not support.

Answer (score 0):

Let's get the terminology straight here:

`docker-compose` deploys docker `containers` on a single host.

`docker-swarm` is the tool to use to deploy `containers` on multiple hosts.

A `cluster` in general, is a set of hosts (or *nodes*), either physical machines or VMs, that work together.

A `Pod` is not a cluster: it is a set of containers that are guaranteed to run on a single node, grouped together and communicating via localhost.

In **Kubernetes**, a deployment will schedule containers on all available `nodes` based on replication policies, node resources, and affinity, so you don't define where a container goes: Kubernetes manages that for you.

You then scale in 2 ways:

- scale the number of instances of a container, by simply increasing it's replication factor (or you can also use auto-scale with defined policy)
- scale the cluster, by adding new nodes (physical or VMs), therefore adding resources to the cluster.